# Jest Error Expected: 200, Number of calls: 0

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I tried to figure out why the test fails for the comment.controller.js file. But, unable to find the cause of it.

```js
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: 200

    Number of calls: 0

    > 96 |       expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
```

But, I'm unable to find the cause of it.

At first, I declared `removeComment` function, in which I first tried to get article data by accepting the article's slug as an argument with the help of `getArticleData` function. If the article exists for it, the next thing I tried is to get the comment for that specific article with the help of `getComment` function that accepts article id as an argument.If the comment exists then I tried to remove comment with `removeComment` function.

```js
const { getArticleData } = require('../services/article.service');
const {
  saveComment,
  getComment,
  getAllComments,
  removeComment,
} = require('../services/comment.service');

exports.removeComment = async (req, res, next) => {
  return getArticleData(req.params.slug)
    .then((article) => {
      return getComment(req.params.id).then(async (comment) => {
        const deletedComment = removeComment(
          req.user._id,
          req.params.slug,
          req.params.id
        );
        if (deletedComment) {
          return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Comment Deleted Successfully' });
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(next);
};
```

To test the code for `removeComment` function, I wrote below unit testing code. In that code, I wanted to write the test suite for unit testing `removeComment` function. In that test suite, I also tried to test both `getArticleData` and `getComment` functions are called at least once and with the necessary arguments.

```js
const articleServiceHelper = require("../../../services/article.service");
const commentHelper = require("../../../services/comment.service");
const mockCommentsData = require("../fixtures/comments.json");

const mockResponse = () => {
  return {
    status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    json: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
  };
};

const mockNext = jest.fn();

const mockUser = {
  _id: "6368ad4347dkhs"
};

const mockArticle = {
  title: "Sample article title",
  description: "Sample article description",
  body: "Sample article body"
};

const mockComment = {
  id: 1,
  createdAt: "2016-02-18T03:22:56.637Z",
  updatedAt: "2016-02-18T03:22:56.637Z",
  body: "It takes a Jacobian"
};

const getArticleSpy = jest.spyOn(articleServiceHelper, "getArticleData").mockResolvedValue(mockArticle);
const getCommentSpy = jest.spyOn(commentHelper, "getComment").mockResolvedValue(mockComment);

describe("Unit tests for comment.controller.js file", () => {
describe("removeComment tests", () => {
    test("If user can remove comment for a specific article", async () => {
      //Arrange
      const mockReq = { params: { id: "5478ad4347dkhs", slug: 'test-article-slug' } };
      const mockRes = mockResponse();
      const { removeComment } = require("../../../controllers/comment.controller");
      //Act
      await removeComment(mockReq, mockRes, mockNext);
      //Assert
      expect(getArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(getArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockReq.params.slug);
      expect(getCommentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(getCommentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockReq.params.id);
      expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
      expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        message: 'Comment Deleted Successfully'
      });
      expect(mockNext).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it took me a while to understand what I was doing wrong. I modified my controller code a little bit and test accordingly. Then it worked for me.

[file: comment.controller.js]

```js
const { getArticleData } = require('../services/article.service');
const {
  saveComment,
  getComment,
  getAllComments,
  deleteComment,
} = require('../services/comment.service');

exports.removeComment = async (req, res, next) => {
  return await getArticleData(req.params.slug)
    .then(async (article) => {
      if (article) {
        return await getComment(req.params.id).then(async (comment) => {
          if (comment) {
            return await deleteComment(req.user._id, req.params.slug, req.params.id).then(
              (deletedComment) => {
                if (deletedComment)
                  return res
                    .status(200)
                    .json({ message: 'Comment Deleted Successfully' });
              }
            );
          }
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(next);
};
```

[file:comment.controller.test.js]

```js
const articleServiceHelper = require("../../../services/article.service");
const commentHelper = require("../../../services/comment.service");

const mockResponse = () => {
  return {
    status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    json: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
  };
};

const mockNext = jest.fn();

const mockArticle = {
  title: "Sample article title",
  description: "Sample article description",
  body: "Sample article body"
};

const mockComment = {
  id: 1,
  createdAt: "2016-02-18T03:22:56.637Z",
  updatedAt: "2016-02-18T03:22:56.637Z",
  body: "It takes a Jacobian",
  author: {
    username: "jake",
    bio: "I work at statefarm",
    image: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHWG8.jpg",
    following: false
  }
};

const getArticleSpy = jest.spyOn(articleServiceHelper, "getArticleData").mockResolvedValue(mockArticle);
const getCommentSpy = jest.spyOn(commentHelper, "getComment").mockResolvedValue(mockComment);
const removeCommentSpy = jest.spyOn(commentHelper, "deleteComment").mockResolvedValue(true);

describe("Unit tests for comment.controller.js file", () => {
  describe("removeComment tests", () => {
    test("If user can remove comment for a specific article", async () => {
      //Arrange
      const mockReq = { params: { id: "5478ad4347dkhs", slug: 'test-article-slug' }, user: { _id: "6368ad4347dkhs" } };
      const mockRes = mockResponse();
      const { removeComment } = require("../../../controllers/comment.controller");
      //Act
      await removeComment(mockReq, mockRes, mockNext);
      //Assert
      expect(getArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(getArticleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockReq.params.slug);
      expect(getCommentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(getCommentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockReq.params.id);
      expect(removeCommentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(removeCommentSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockReq.user._id, mockReq.params.slug, mockReq.params.id);
      expect(mockRes.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
      expect(mockRes.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        message: 'Comment Deleted Successfully'
      });
      expect(mockNext).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```